# I have a list of objects and would like to return an attribute with another attribute

Tags: django

If my objects were 
`{(title: 'one', content: 'foo'), (title: 'two', content: 'bar')}`
how would I go about getting 'for' and 'bar' into my template?

Something like this:

```
{% for content in content_list where content.title='one'}
{{ content.content }}
```

Resulting in 'foo'.

```
{% for content in content_list where content.title='two'}
{{ content.content }}
```

Resulting in 'bar'.

Comment: why are you not using if ??

Comment: It will be faster and readable to add, two list in the your template context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
{% for content in content_list %}
    {% if content.title == 'two' %}
        {{ content.content }}
    {% else %}
        {{ content.content }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Note: Only if list is small

Comment: Hmm this gives a:
TemplateSyntaxError at /
Invalid block tag on line 114: 'endfor', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Which doesn't make any sense to me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split your content in columns, just create a list for each kind of object and iterate over them.

In your view, do something like this:

```
l1 = [(title: 'one', content: 'foo'),] # All the objects with title 'one'
l2 = [(title: 'two', content: 'bar'),] # All the objects with title 'two'
context = {'content_list1': l1, 'content_list2': l2}
```

And in your html iterate over each list:

```
{% for content in content_list1 %}
{{ content.content }}
{% endfor %}

{% for content in content_list2 %}
{{ content.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

I hope it's that what you are looking for.